# What is causing this SQLException?

Tags: java, sql

I'm getting the following error :

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1.

While trying to run the following code:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO `tutors`.`appointments`"
        + "(`tutorID`, `tuteeName`, `tuteeEmail`, `time`, `date`)"
        + ("VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?");
 try {
     PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
     ps.setInt(1, working.get(0).getTutorID());
     ps.setString(2, tuteeName);
     ps.setString(3, tuteeEmail);
     ps.setDate(4, date);
     ps.setTime(5, time);
     ps.executeUpdate();
```

What is it producing the `' '` that the exception is referring to? I'm just learning to work with SQL in java, so I'm sure this is just a silly syntactical error...

Comment: always try to execute the query once in a client before putting it to code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You were not closing the VALUES parenthesis:

```
 String sql = "INSERT INTO `tutors`.`appointments`"
            + " (`tutorID`, `tuteeName`, `tuteeEmail`, `time`, `date`)"
            +  ("VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
```

Comment: spacing isn't really the problem but the lacking of `)` of the `VALUES` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Problem with your sql string. It should be

```
"INSERT INTO `tutors`.`appointments`"
            + "(`tutorID`, `tuteeName`, `tuteeEmail`, `time`, `date`)"
            + "VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

Answer (score 0):

may be in your first '(' in third line.

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO `tutors`.`appointments`"
    + "(`tutorID`, `tuteeName`, `tuteeEmail`, `time`, `date`)"
    + ("VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?");
```

it should be

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO `tutors`.`appointments`"
    + " (`tutorID`, `tuteeName`, `tuteeEmail`, `time`, `date`)"
    + " VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?");
```

add some space in begining of second and third line also.